# List iteration throws ConcurrentModificationException in Java 8 when sorting already sorted list

Tags: java, list, sorting, iteration, concurrentmodification

Just in case anyone else has a similar issue, I thought I'd post my issue and solution here.

Basically, I had code that was working fine under Java7, but was consistently throwing a ConcurrentModificationException in Java8. The structure was basically this:

```
List<FormatData> formats = service.getFormat(type);
for (FormatData f : formats) {
    /* Do stuff here */
}
```

However, part of the "Do stuff here" part ended up calling the same `service.getFormat(type)` function and returning the same list. However, that same function looked up the list but also sorted the list. In Java7, since the list was already sorted, it didn't modify it. In Java8, it treats re-sorting a sorted list as having been modified.

Comment: Sorting while you also iterate the list, *is* modifying it. It sounds that `.getFormat()` is returning a data structure that should be internal to `service`. It should probably return a copy, or an [unmodifiable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) view of the list instead.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing after tracking down the issue. The second call to the service was hidden a couple of layers down. Stepping through the function to track down the moment where the list's variables showed another modification helped figure out where the culprit was.

Comment: My main point was that Sorting a sorted list is handled slightly differently in Java7 and Java8... Java7 may not treat it as having been modified, while Java8 does (correctly). Basically it pointed out a flaw in my programming that was both inefficient and wrong :)

Comment: It's actually a good thing that the new version recognizes some more unsafe modifications. Unfortunately `ConcurrentModificationException` is not guaranteed to be thrown in all dangerous cases, it **may be thrown**, but only if the problem is detected. Just because such exception is not thrown, it does not mean your code is thread safe.

Comment: try fail safe ( thread safe) collections. in your case copyOnWriteArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was twofold, either one would have worked. 
First of all, I moved the sorting away from the retrieve function so I wouldn't waste time - instead I moved it to the load function where it should have been in the first place.
Secondly, in a lesser used function that returned the same list but sorted differently, I just created a new list, which I then sorted and returned:

```
result = new ArrayList(oldList);
Collections.sort(result, otherComparator);
```

In addition, before returning on either side, I added this to ensure no more modifications can occur without throwing exceptions:

```
result = (result==null) ? null : Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
```